# ggplot2 prints twice when inside lapply() loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

When creating a set of two graphs, then printing inside a lapply loop will print twice in RStudio Plots Panel.

```
x=1:7
y=1:7
df1 = data.frame(x=x,y=y)
x=10:70
y=10:70
df2 = data.frame(x=x,y=y)
db <- list(df1, df2)

# Given a data frame, the function below creates a graph
create.graph <- function (df){
  p <- ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()
  # here goes other stuff, such as ggsave()
  return (p)
}

# collect.graph is a list of generated graphs
collect.graph <- lapply(db,create.graph)

# Finally, lapply prints the list of collected graphs
lapply(collect.graph,print)
```

The code works ok, but it generates two sets of graphs in RStudio instead of only one.

How to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Just `print(collect.graph)`.

Comment: Ronak, I want to print both objects. However, when I use lapply for some reason it prints both objects twice. @www 's suggestion solved the problem. But I still don´t understand why lapply doesn't work properly... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object gets printed twice is because one output is from `lapply` and the other one is from `print`. Check

```
lapply(1:5, print)

#[1] 1
#[1] 2
#[1] 3
#[1] 4
#[1] 5
#[[1]]
#[1] 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 3

#[[4]]
#[1] 4

#[[5]]
#[1] 5
```

Here, the first part of 1-5 is coming from `print` whereas the next part of 1-5 which is in a list is returned from `lapply`.

From `?lapply`

> lapply returns a list of the same length as X, each element of which is the result of applying FUN to the corresponding element of X.

So when you apply `lapply` it returns the same object back which gets displayed and since the `FUN` argument is `print` it applies that function to every object in `lapply` thus printing it twice.

The workaround as suggested by @www is use `print(collect.graph)` or just `collect.graph` in the console to print it only once.

Comment: Thank you Ronak. However, if you code `a <- lapply (1:5,print)`,  `a` output will be different from `lapply (1:5,print)`. Weird.... Actually, I noticed that lapply() echoes a vector when assigning, then returns the output of FUN.

Comment: Yes, if you do `a <- lapply (1:5,print)` it prints the 1:5 in the console and returns the 1:5 in list to `a`. Similarly, if you do `a <- lapply(collect.graph,print)` it will print both the object only once and then `a` would also have the same object.